# Is there a way to access the HTML element class name a php function is enclosed within?

Tags: php, css, dom

So for example if I have:

```
<div class="menu">
    <?php myFunction() ?>
</div>
```

Is there some way of checking in `myFunction()` that the wrapping `div` has a class of `menu`?

Comment: PHP is run at the server before HTML is sent to the browser. At the time when the PHP function is called, there is no way for it to know that it will ultimately be wrapped with a particular html tag / css class.

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry about that!

Comment: I guess the sane approach would be to set the class with PHP. But it all depends on the overall context, which we know nothing about.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I have a set of tabs, each of which displays the result of a php function (i.e. tab one runs myFunction("tab1") etc) - unfortunately something weird is going on and when the page loads the default tab shows the result of all the functions. I had thought of checking in the function whether it was running under the active tab as a quick solution, but you have confirmed my suspicions that it won't work. I'll make a new question with a more detailed description of my problem rather than clutter this one.

Comment: In case you are interested, an expanded explanation of my problem is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503521/using-php-to-display-content-in-jquery-tabs

Answer (score 2):

*EDITED*

Sorry, misread OP.

You CAN do it, but it would be incredibly difficult (you would use `output buffering` after PHP has generated the page and then `XSL` to parse and traverse the outputted document).

A better way would be to use JavaScript since this is client-side, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the PHP function at the point, why not pass the class through to the function:

```
<div class="menu">
    <?php myFunction("menu") ?>
</div>
```

Your php function declaration would look like this:

```
function myFunction($className)
{
    //Your code.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo, been doing to much C# :P